# How much data can my Hadoop cluster handle?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a 4 node cluster configured to have 1 Namenode and 3 datanodes. Im performing a TPCH benchmark and i would like to know how much data you think my cluster can handle without affecting query response times. My total available HD size is about 700GB, each node has cpu with 8 cores and 16GB of RAM.

I saw some calculations that we could do to find the volume limit but i didnt understand IT, if someone could explain on a simple way how to calculate the data volume that a cluster can handle it would be very helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use 70 to 80 % of space in ur cluster to store the data, remaining will be used for processing and to store intermediate results in ur cluster.

This way performance will not be impacted

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you already configured your 4 node cluster. You can go and check in NN webUI-->Configured capacity section to find out the storage details, Let me know if you find any difficulties.